# IPhone 5 power button not responsive

Tags: iphone

Recently the power button on my iPhone 5 has become hard to press, and slow to come back up after being pressed.

**Update** :
As I was typing this I was repeatedly pressing the power button. It eventually returned to its normal position. I am adding this question anyway because I want to know if anyone else has experienced this issue and if so did they had to take their phone into Apple for repair (or talked to a Apple rep that recommended they take it in). (i.e is it a symptom of a bigger problem>)

**Update**  :
It appears to continue to stick at times. I'm going to bring it in next chance I get. Thanks. Note: It's fairly cold here some days (10'F) I'll have to check that next time it happens (probably not).

Comment: I've had problems with the home button on earlier models of iPhone, but never the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this sounds like a hardware problem. It wouldn't be software causing that. Chances are it's simply a bad switch. Hopefully you have AppleCare. If so, wait until it gets bad then take it in. They probably would just replace it. Otherwise - purchase AppleCare if you're still within the time. ;-)

I suppose there is also the possibility something like that could come from something somehow getting in the switch, or damage from a drop. Likely not the case for you, but I think it could happen.

Again, in conclusion, it's probably a bad switch.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **Bassplayer** (great name BTW) in that it's a hardware issue. But just to expand on it, I've had the same issue with my iPhone 4S and because I bought it used, taking it to the Apple store isn't an option.

My solution until I get a new phone, is to use the ***AssistiveTouch*** to turn my phone off and put it to sleep (along with other functions like taking a screenshot).

If you haven't heard, the *AssistiveTouch* is a white, translucent dot on the screen that when tapped opens a context menu that will give you options for Sleep mode, powering off, among others.

You can turn this on in:

> **Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch On**

You can also toggle the display of the dot with:

> **Settings > General > Accessibility > Triple-click Home** set to **AssistiveTouch**.

This way you can hide the white dot when it gets in the way.

Comment: Thanks! Btw the triple-click home is under General > Accessibility > Accessibility Shortcut -> select "Assistive Touch"